# Why does a semicolon in ejs template throws error

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

In the following code if the semicolon is removed the template engine does not throw error, else the error is thrown.

```
<ul>
  <% for (i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) { %>
      <%= JSON.stringify(array[i]); %>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

Although putting semicolon syntactically correct, why does the template engine throw error ?

Comment: The content of `<=%` is an expression, not a statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @torazaburo said, the contents between `<=%` and `%>` are an expression that gets parsed by ejs. However, think of it this way:

Your goal is to render the contents returned from `JSON.stringify` to the page right? So in that case, think of ejs expressions as implicitly calling `.toString()` on the result of the expression and then inserting that string into the page. By adding a semi-colon you've terminated the statement without assigning the returned value to anything.